# Rotate video 90 degrees in AVPlayerViewController - possible?

Tags: ios, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller, avplayerlayer, avkit

I cannot figure out how to rotate the video 90 degrees in `AVPlayerViewController`, anyone have any ideas as to how to do this? I'm unsure how to access the `AVPlayerLayer` as you normally would.

Comment: Please explain yourself, what is your real needs to help you, best regards

Comment: @ReinierMelian Your answer worked, you just didn't specify the necessary frame change.

Comment: Ok, undeleted then, I will check the frame change and the issue of interaction disabled

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with this code, using AffineTransform we rotate the view but we need also adjust the frame

**EDITED**

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
  self.avPlayerViewController?.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat((90 * Double.pi)/180))
  self.avPlayerViewController?.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (self.avPlayerViewController?.view.frame.size.height)!, height: (self.avPlayerViewController?.view.frame.size.width)!)
}
```

Work just fine, was tested

Hope this helps you

Comment: Doesn't work at all for me. Leaves white on the top and bottom and disables interaction.

Comment: You need rotate and adjust the frame? is what you need?

Comment: @DougSmith check my answer again, was edited, let me know if solves your problem now, best regards