# How to enable AVPlayerViewController to autorotate without subclassing?

Tags: ios, landscape, avplayerviewcontroller

I have an app that is supposed to work only in landscape mode. The app needs to play a video. Before iOS 13, I used an `MPMediaPlayerViewController` by subclassing it and overriding `shouldAutorotate`. Now I see that the replacement class `AVPlayerViewController` doesn't support subclassing (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller). How do I enable autorotation without subclassing?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45110393/rotate-video-90-degrees-in-avplayerviewcontroller-possible/45110445#45110445 maybe can help you some way

Comment: Reiner, thanks. It is indeed a workaround that works if the device is in LandscapeLeft orientation. However, if I rotate the device while the video is playing, the video automatically rotates to the wrong orientation. I can't understand why auto rotations are not officially supported anymore...